# It's not possible to override Django EmailField label

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have declared my signup form (in which user can choose a username and set his email; second step for django-allauth) as follows:

```py
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('username'),
            Field('email'),
            FormActions(
                Submit('do', u'Reģistrēties', css_class='btn-primary')
            )
        )

        self.fields['username'].label = u'Lietotāja vārds'
        self.fields['email'].label = 'Epasts'

    def save(self, user):
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.save()
```

The problem I'm having - I can override username label but not email. Checking initial email field label yields `None`.

Is it possible to override EmailField label (and `(optional)` part of label)? Should I switch to i18n altogether (if in that way I can fully control field labels, error messages etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after I migrated to i18n. You have to extend from BaseSignupForm if you want  hardcoded localiziation of field labels and validation error messages. But I'd recommend to stick with built in localization.